# How can I find all matches in any position in the string using regular expression (re.finditer) in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I am using python regular expression (regex) to find all the matches in any string position (say "GgGAT", frame 1 is Gg.. and frame2 is gG..). I need to used re.finditer method. My code below gives me only `"Gg"` while I need both `"Gg"` and `"gG"`;

```
import re

data="ACGTGgGTT" 
for match in re.finditer(r'GG|gg|Gg|gG', data):
   print (match)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "frame"?

Comment: The regex can be trivially simplified to `[Gg][Gg]`, or just use `(r'gg', data, re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Did you try Re.findall or Re.match? Not sure what is your use case.

Comment: Great point @tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex lookahead using `?=...` synthax:

```
re.finditer(r"(?=(GG|gg|Gg|gG))", data)
```

Comment: Please write the output.

Comment: This worked perfectly :)

Comment: @GiladGreen I gave your answer a vote, but not sure how to do what you suggesting

Comment: @GiladGreen Done!

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps:

```
import re

data="ACGTGgGTTgGg" 
for match in re.finditer(r'GG|gg|Gg|gG', data):
   for i in range(match.start(),match.end()):
       print (data[i]+data[i+1])
```

Output:

```
Gg
gG
gG
Gg
```

Comment: I need to iterate the matches so have to use "finditer" :)

Comment: Have updated the code.. please check if it helps..

Comment: Thanks, but if you add another nt at the end you see it's not working

Comment: What do you mean by nt? did not get it..

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
data="ACGTGgGTgGTGGgg" 
matches = re.findall(r'G{2}', data,re.IGNORECASE) # Or re.I
print(matches)
>> ['Gg', 'gG', 'GG', 'gg']
```

**EDIT**

```
import re
data="ACGTGgGTgGTGGgg" 
for match in re.finditer(r'G{2}', data,re.IGNORECASE):
    print(match)
>>> 
<re.Match object; span=(4, 6), match='Gg'>
<re.Match object; span=(8, 10), match='gG'>
<re.Match object; span=(11, 13), match='GG'>
<re.Match object; span=(13, 15), match='gg'>
```

Comment: I need to iterate the matches so have to use "finditer" :)